# How to translate Entityform type name

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

I created a form using [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) module. I'm not able to translate name of entity form type. How is it possible to translate name for each enabled language?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! I was using latest stable release 7.x-2.0-rc1. It does not support i18n but they add a sub module which its name is entityform translation in dev version (7.x-2.x-dev). Once this module is enabled, a translate link appears on the table list of entity form types.